# Cache memory design - address decoding

Tags: caching, memory, cpu

I was given the following problem:

A CPU generates 32 bit addresses for a byte addressable memory. Design an 8 KB cache memory for this CPU (8 KB is the cache size only for the data; it does not include the tag). The block size is 32 bytes. Show the block diagram, and the address decoding for direct mapped cache memory.

I determined that:

- 8 bits are needed for indexing
- 5 bits are needed for block offset
- 19 bits for the tag.

[image]

Is my solution correct? How should I do the decoding?

Answer (score 1):

The numbers seem correct, however it is always worth pointing out in your solution that you're taking cache associativity under account. Specifically, `32-8-5=19` is only valid when the cache is directly mapped.

The decoding part is nicely illustrated in your drawing – it's simply the act of taking 32 bits of the address as used by the CPU apart into the tag, index, and offset fields.